# Si ejecuto una función dentro de la otra, no se ejecuta como debería

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo estas funciones javascript:

```
function sumarVentas(){
    $(function(){
        if($('#totalPagar').val() == '')
        var parr = 0;
        else var parr = parseFloat($('#totalPagar').val());
        $('.subTotalVenta').each(function(e, item){
            parr += (parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g, '')));
            console.log('pasó por el loop');
        });
        $('#totalPagar').val(parr.toFixed(2));
    });
}

function editarPromocion(id){
    const url = base_url + 'promociones/buscarPorId/?id=' + id;
    const x = '';
    $.get(base_url + 'promociones/buscarPorId/', 'id=' + id, function(a){
        const e = JSON.parse(a);
        const x = JSON.parse(e[0].productos);
        let n = '', i = 0, html = '';
        $(x).each(function(indice, elemento){
            ++n;
            let id = x[n-1]['id'], cantidad = x[n-1]['cantidad'];
            $.post(base_url + 'productos/mostrarDatos', JSON.stringify([{id: x[n-1]['id'], cantidad: x[n-1]['cantidad']}]), function (res){
                producto = $.parseJSON(res);
                html += `<tr data-prod="${id}">
                            <td>${producto['productos'][0]['nombre']}</td>
                            <td>${producto['productos'][0]['precio_venta']}</td>
                            <td width="100">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control inputCantidad" data-id="${id}" onchange="cambiarcantidad(${id}, this.value)" value="${cantidad}">
                            </td>
                            <td id="subTotalVenta" class="subTotalVenta">${producto['productos'][0]['subTotalVenta']}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminar" data-id="${id}" onclick="eliminarProducto(${id}, true);" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>`;
                        tblPromociones.innerHTML = html;
            });
        });

    });
    return sumarVentas();
}
```

Lo que debería hacer sumarVentas(); al final es sumar todos los .subTotalVenta que se añadieron con los $.post del bucle de arriba, pero al ejecutar la función principal en la consola, devuelve el total en $0.00 como si no los tomara en cuenta, y no imprime el "pasó por el loop" de la función sumarVentas();

Los 3 productos añadidos correctamente en la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función llamada al final de editarPromocion() devuelve las sumatorias en 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ejecuto sumarVentas(); manualmente desde la consola, efectivamente la función se ejecuta normalmente y hace el loop por los 3 productos sumando correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta tiene que ver con, por qué no se ejecuta correctamente el sumarVentas() al hacer el llamado en la función principal y sí si lo hago manualmente, probé poniendo sin el return y tampoco funciona y probé colocando la función de sumatorias dentro un .done() al final del $.post donde se obtienen los productos pero se ejecuta 8 veces y arroja un importe incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos puntos que tienes que revisar, intenta ejecutar la función despues del $.get

como en el ejemplo que sigue:

```
   function editarPromocion(id){
        const url = base_url + 'promociones/buscarPorId/?id=' + id;
        const x = '';
        $.get(base_url + 'promociones/buscarPorId/', 'id=' + id, function(a){
            const e = JSON.parse(a);
            const x = JSON.parse(e[0].productos);
            let n = '', i = 0, html = '';
            $(x).each(function(indice, elemento){
                ++n;
                let id = x[n-1]['id'], cantidad = x[n-1]['cantidad'];
                $.post(base_url + 'productos/mostrarDatos', JSON.stringify([{id: x[n-1]['id'], cantidad: x[n-1]['cantidad']}]), function (res){
                    producto = $.parseJSON(res);
                    html += `<tr data-prod="${id}">
                                <td>${producto['productos'][0]['nombre']}</td>
                                <td>${producto['productos'][0]['precio_venta']}</td>
                                <td width="100">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control inputCantidad" data-id="${id}" onchange="cambiarcantidad(${id}, this.value)" value="${cantidad}">
                                </td>
                                <td id="subTotalVenta" class="subTotalVenta">${producto['productos'][0]['subTotalVenta']}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminar" data-id="${id}" onclick="eliminarProducto(${id}, true);" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></td>
                            </tr>`;
                            tblPromociones.innerHTML = html;
                });
            });
           debugger;
           sumarVentas();
        });
        return ;
    }
```

Puse un debugger para detener la ejecución del código, si vez que entrá a "sumarVentas()" antes de que termine el get, entonces mete la función adentro del get

Comment: Al darle play al debugger la función entra correctamente y se muestra el importe correcto, qué extraño.
https://i.imgur.com/SRmSBkf.png

Comment: Puede ser que el debugger le dió tiempo a el $.get de terminar,
intenta usando un fetch en vez de $.get y al final del Then mandas llamar "sumaVentas()"